# current and previous value comparison within foreach

Tags: c#, if-statement

Any solution is appreciated, not tied to this approach.

```
foreach(var x in xs){
    var y = getValuesfromX(x);

    foreach(var yvalue in y){

        //Here I want if(yvalue is LESS than 100 and if (yvalue - previousyvalue) not   GEATER than 30){

       // perform action

        //else, quit looping xs am not interested anymore after the difference reached 30
```

Comment: Don't use a foreach use a for loop. Then you can reference any item.

Comment: How about the first yvalue? Just compare with 100 since there is no previous value?

Comment: @PreetSangha: You're assuming that `getValuesFromX` returns something like a `List<T>`. It may not - it may just return `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet - Yes but if it isn't then this may well be a good enough reason to convert the data - if possible. Or perhaps use multiple passes over the data if needed.

Comment: @PreetSangha: It *may* be - but it may not be. Multiple passes over the data may not be possible... and most importantly, your comment didn't appear to consider any of these, it just *assumed* that you could use a `for` loop with an index.

Comment: @jonskeet Agreed there is a strong assumption. But in my defence I'd say within the very limited context supplied in the question, it's a valid assumption until it's rejected as invalid/impractical etc. This is the reason I made a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are approaches you could take using the `Zip` operator, but otherwise it's probably simplest to just keep the previous value - or a *limit* for the next value - as a variable:

```
foreach (var x in xs)
{
    var ys = GetValuesForX(x);
    int limit = int.MaxValue; // Any value is fine to start with.
    foreach (var y in ys)
    {
        if (y > limit)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (y < 100)
        {
            // Take some action 
        }
        limit = y + 30;
    }
}
```

Note that this will cause problems if `y` can ever be `int.MaxValue - 30`.

Comment: you miss the `if (yvalue - previousyvalue) not   GEATER than 30` part and depending on his `action` a for-loop would maybe be better

Comment: but here, if my limit is 140(definately y can be 140 - 30 in any limit i take) and I want the difference of current - previous to be < 30 , so if I assume initial value of previousyvalue = 0 then its never gonna enter the loop on the first iteration when my first value is 31

Comment: @WiiMaxx: I'm not missing that - that's the point of `limit`. And with a `for` loop, you appear to be *assuming* that this is an indexed collection.

Comment: @TrackmeifYouCan: I'm not assuming any initial value of `previousyvalue` - I'm starting with a limit of `MaxValue` so that you'll *never* break on the first iteration.

Comment: ohh i miss the `not` be for `GEATER`my fault, so +1 :)